# how to run a function in my google app script via api using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-apps-script

I want to run a function in my google app script file. but how can i run it via api in an external website. Help anyone please.

I tried to send an api request as this
target script code.gs

```
 function addtext(sheetId) {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
   ss.appendRow(['test', 'blabla'])
   });
 }
```

and javascript as this
     var scriptId = "";

```
 // Initialize parameters for function call.
 var sheetId = "<ENTER_ID_OF_SPREADSHEET_TO_EXAMINE_HERE>";

 // Create execution request.
 var request = {
   'function': 'addtext',
   'parameters': [sheetId],
   'devMode': true  
 };

// Make the request.
 function apire() {
   gapi.client.request({
   'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
   'path': 'v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run',
   'method': 'POST',
   'body': request
   });
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can follow [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js):

## [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

> [*google.script.run*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API that allows HTML-service pages to call server-side Apps Script functions. The following example shows the most basic functionality of `google.script.run` — [*calling a function on the server*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)) from client-side JavaScript.

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<script>
google.script.run.doSomething();
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function doSomething() {
Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

> For an in-depth [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample), complete the steps described in the rest of this page, and in about five minutes you'll have a simple JavaScript application that makes requests to the Google Apps Script Execution API.